# Wordpress post preview link redirecting on home page. I want to stop it

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have laravel website and there is blog folder which contain wordpress blog. In my htaccess I want some path that allow to open otherwise redirect on home. So my post preview link also redirect on home page. I want to stop it. Preview link is like  https://www.test.com/?p=16286. I want to redirect on particular page. Below is my htaccess code

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/my-form
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/save_subscribe_user
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/demo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/xamarin-app-development
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/xamarin-app-development-inner
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/web-and-mobile-app-development
RewriteCond $1 !^(blog|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1 [L,QSA]


## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js
</FilesMatch>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    #This line added to allow blog in URL and allow routing through Laravel
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/    

    #Blog post preview URL
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([0-9]*)
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.test.com/?p=%1&preview=true [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: With this code It redirecting on home page

Comment: Now its give me redirected you too many times error

Comment: you should exclude this from general rules , paste your htaccess

Comment: Here is my whole htaccess

Answer (score 0):

These two lines :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([0-9]*)
RewriteRule ^ http://www.test.com/?p=%1&preview=true [R=301,L]
```

The query string is start with numerical value as the target you need to redirect to so , it will be rewritied more and more and you could be more specific , as you menthioned in quistion , by add `$` to `^p=([0-9]*)$` to be sperated from the new one . change your rules like this :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.test.com/?p=%1&preview=true [R=301,L]
```

If that not ok and you need to match this query string before any rewriting rule just put it up before that particulaar step.

**Note:** clear browser cache then test

Comment: It is redirecting on home page

Comment: @P.patel put them at Top after first RewriteEngine On

Comment: I have put it on top. But still redirecting on home page

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
This condition is main. If I removed this then it is working. But it stop my main page redirection

Comment: Is there any way to put with this condition because I can't remove it